# Print result of JS file in html

Tags: javascript, html, function, printing

So I have an html file with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(getHighestCacheMan());
</script>
```

And I have this Javascript code in a .js file with the code:

```
function getHighestCacheMan()
{
    var cache = currentCaches[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < currentCaches.length; i++) {
    if(currentCaches[i].altitude != -32768)
        if(currentCaches[i].altitude > cache.altitude)
        cache = currentCaches[i];
    }
    return cache.name;
}
```

The files are correctly linked together and everything else that is intertwined between files works as intended.

It doesn't show anything.
Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: innerHTML should work

Comment: What do you expect the final output to be?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It sounds like you want to get an element by ID and then change its inner HTML to the result of the function, but can't be sure until you elaborate on your goal.

Comment: Yes, update an existing element in the DOM, `document.write` is almost never the thing to use: `document.getElementById("the_id").innerHTML = getHighestCacheMan();`  (Remember not to do this until the document is ready)

Comment: This is supposed to output a "string" (cache.name). This value will change as the caches stored are updated/removed. @SimonVisser

Comment: ^ This is the output @Dekel

Comment: But if you do `document.write` it only output's it to the screen (as part of the DOM) and not as a javascript variable that you can use... so I'm really not sure what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a id="demo"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=getHighestCacheMan();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using innerHTML:

```js
var currentCaches = [ {altitude: 12, name: "Jhon"}, {altitude: 23, name: "peter"}, {altitude: 10, name: "francisco"}, {altitude: 590, name: "Eddy"}];
function getHighestCacheMan()
{
    var cache = currentCaches[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < currentCaches.length; i++) {
    if(currentCaches[i].altitude != -32768)
        if(currentCaches[i].altitude > cache.altitude)
            cache = currentCaches[i];
    }
    return cache.name;
}

document.getElementById("HighestCacheMan").innerHTML = getHighestCacheMan();
```

```html
<div id="HighestCacheMan"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by a lot of people the answer was indeed to use innerHTML.

As so I now have in my .html:

```
<br />Name: <SPAN id='cacheName'></SPAN>
```

and on my  .js:

```
document.getElementById('cacheName').innerHTML = highestCache.name;
```

And it now works as intended! Thank you to everybody who helped.